# Is there any way to multiply 2 matrices element by element scilab

Tags: matrix, scilab

Anyone knows if there is any way to multiple 2 matrices element by element

```
->(u^i)'
ans  =

1.    1.3    1.69  

-->d^j
ans  =

0.25  
0.5   
1.    
-->u^(i)'*d^(j)
ans  =

2.59
```

I don't want to receive a scalar as in this case, but a matrix of element-wise multiplication. I wanna have a element-wise multiplication like 1*0.25, 1.3*0.25, 1.69*1.
Any suggestion how can I do this ?

Comment: You should transpose one of the vectors (row or column) before you apply element-wise multiplication operation depending on what you want to get.
For example:

    A = [1.    1.3    1.69]
    B=[0.25;0.5;1.] 
    C = A'.*B
    D =A.*B'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for dot product .* (or perhaps more appropriately "dot star")? http://www.math.fsu.edu/~bellenot/class/f07/em2/scilab/scilab-dot

Comment: Dot product does not give back a matrix, but a scalar.   I wanna have a element-wise multiplication like 1*0.25, 1.3*0.25, 1.69*1

Comment: .* as mentioned in the link I included is an element-wise multiplication. I don't know scilab specifically but it would work on Matlab and Octave.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it is `.*`

See [this tutorial](http://www.scilabtutorials.com/2014/06/matrice-and-element-wise-multiplication.htmlhttp://www.scilabtutorials.com/2014/06/matrice-and-element-wise-multiplication.html?m=1) about multiplication in SciLab.